# Hierarchical RDBMS Query spanning across multiple tables with in clause

Tags: sql, oracle, rdbms, recursive-query

I have  a Product table. Each product has at least one version maintained in PROD_VERSION (ProdID references Product.ProdID)

Now each version of a Product can have 0 or many sub-products. The relationship is stored in ProdAssoc table (ParentVersionID references PROD_VERSION.version_D, childProdId references Product.ProdID)

Now while creating a new Product from UI, a user can choose zero or many child products.

I need to check if any existing Composite Product has the same set of atomic products(having no child product) as children directly or indirectly.

I've come up with

```
 SELECT level, view1.* FROM 
  (SELECT ps.ProdID pid, cpsn.ParentVersionID , cpsn.childProdId apid
    FROM Product ps, PROD_VERSION psv, ProdAssoc cpsn 
    WHERE psv.version_D = cpsn.ParentVersionID 
       AND ps.ProdID = psv.ProdID ) view1
   CONNECT BY prior pid = apid
   START WITH apid IN (318, 323, 320);
```

Any help/improvement in this regard will be highly appreciated.

**Environment**

**DB:** Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE   12.1.0.2.0  Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production

**Java:** 
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)

**Server:**  Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform - Version 6.3.3.GA

**OS:** Linux kolps46 2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jun 6 18:30:54 EDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: check out `connect by` or see posts tagged with `oracle` and `recursive-query`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recursive-query+oracle

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name,  I've just come up with SELECT level,
  view1.*
FROM
  (SELECT ps.ProdID pid,
    cpsn.ParentVersionID ,
    cpsn.childProdId  apid
  FROM Product  ps,
    PROD_VERSION psv,
    ProdAssoc cpsn
  WHERE psv.version_D = cpsn.ParentVersionID 
  AND ps.ProdID           = psv.ProdID
  ) view1
  CONNECT BY prior pid = apid
  START WITH apid     IN (318, 323, 320);    Can it be improved further?

Comment: Please edit your question to include additional information.  Or post it as an answer.